# What is this example unit test in the official neo4j documention actually testing?

Tags: java, unit-testing, neo4j

The neo4j documentation has [this page about creating unit tests for neo4j.](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tutorials-java-unit-testing.html)

Essentially it suggests that we create a mock database using

`graphDb = new TestGraphDatabaseFactory().newImpermanentDatabase();`

in our setup method and test against that.

The question is - if you look at the [full test source code they've given](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/2.3.3/community/embedded-examples/src/test/java/org/neo4j/examples/Neo4jBasicDocTest.java), the test doesn't appear to be actually testing any function. It appears to be tautologically testing that the mocked database is storing and retrieving results correctly.

Am I missing something here? - Is there another example where it tests against some actual business code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is just one of the simplest unit test examples. There are many the other examples in [the same directory](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/tree/2.3.3/community/embedded-examples/src/test/java/org/neo4j/examples).